# Part 3 of Django Tutorial-- 'module' object has no attribute 'detail'

Tags: python, django

I've looked around at what other people have done in similar situations, I checked my settings.py file in INSTALLED_APPS for polls, even added 'detail', (which broke things). I also checked for all of my `__init__.py` files, which they all seem to be in places in which they belong. When I put an `__init__.py` file in /Users/apisgirl/mysite/polls/templates/polls (which is what the tutorial suggested I do at this stage, and is where I'm working on my templates) it breaks everything. So that's a no go.

This is currently how things are broken:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/apisgirl/mysite/mysite/urls.py" in <module>
  19.     url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  25.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/apisgirl/mysite/polls/urls.py" in <module>
  10.                        url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'detail'
```

As well I am using a recent version of osx (all updated and what-not), so I figure this is a fault of my own and I'm simply missing some part here.

I can't think of anything else that I've done, I insured that checked settings.py, all of my urls.py files, and my views.py file for anything I may have missed. I have naturally read over the tutorial a number of times looking for the answer there. I'm just not getting it.

Edit: Is it something to do with this line in mysite/polls/urls.py? I've checked and this is what it looks like in the tutorial. So is this a version issue?

```
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

At request here is my polls/views.py file, it has some code from part 4, as I started to look ahead for answers:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader

from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = Context({
                      'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
                      })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))


def results(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'poll': poll})

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                      'poll': p,
                      'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
                      })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,))),
```

Comment: Show us your `/Users/apisgirl/mysite/polls/views.py`.

Comment: Ok, I suggest checking it again and comparinig with the tutorial. It's missing something and I'm sure it's very easy to deduce what exactly is missing.

Comment: It is looking for a view with the name `detail` in views.py. But it did not find any

Comment: I finally fixed it. Now I've managed to break another thing, but I feel much better prepared for this now that I went over part 3 again. Thanks so much. :D @kirelagin

Comment: the ```path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),``` of the polls/urls.py should have the ```detail``` function in the polls/views.py. check if they are accordingly with the third tutorial. If yes  and you continue having the same issue double check if you don't forget saving the file after you add the code in each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says

```
'module' object has no attribute 'detail'
```

and stack trace shows that it occured at this line:

```
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

It's pretty clear that interpreter is trying to tell us that `views` module (which corresponds to your `views.py` file) doesn't have an attribute `detail` (here “attribute” means “whatever you access with dot-notation”, that is: variable, function, method, …whatever).

Indeed, your `views.py` is missing the `detail` function. Check part 3 of the tutorial for [its defintion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views).